# Updating Android SDK Version

Tags: android

Friend's,
       I want to know how to change currently using android sdk to another,(i.e) i'm using   android-sdk_r04-windows in my eclipse,suppose if i need to change it for android-sdk_r07-windows,how can i proceed,whether simply delete android-sdk_r04-windows from drive and to download and paste android-sdk_r07-windows,is't enough or something i need to do.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Eclipse, go to Window > Android SDK and AVD Manager. Then, in Available Packages, select the SDK versions you want to install. (note that you might also want to select Android SDK Tools)
When the installation is finished, you should also update the ADT plugin for Eclipse.

To use a certain SDK release for you project, go to project properties (right click on the project and select Properties) and select (from the Android page) the desired Project Build Target.